# Xamarin.Forms android app won't build anymore after adding "Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" to it

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, visual-studio-2019

After adding "Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" to any Xamarin.Forms android application it won't build anymore due to

```
Did not find reference matching RestoreAssemblyResources AssemblyName metadata 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging'
```

with the warning

```
esolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Same issue happens when creating a new xamarin.forms project and adding said package to the .android application via nuget (no errors here).

Adding "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" does not help either.

(Thus cleaning the project, reinstalling the package, running it in admin mode, etc.. won't fix it)

Comment: I would suggest try clearing your NuGet cache (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Clear All NuGet Cache(s)) and then reinstalling the package. I just tried adding Firebase.Messaging to a Xamarin.Forms Android project in VS 2019 and everything was fine.

Comment: You're a hero, worked like a charm!

Comment: @Kalerion If solved this problem,remember to post an answer and mark it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nicks comment solved the issue:

> I would suggest try clearing your NuGet cache (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Clear All NuGet Cache(s)) and then reinstalling the package. I just tried adding Firebase.Messaging to a Xamarin.Forms Android project in VS 2019 and everything was fine